# jquery: "Exception thrown and not caught" in IE8, but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

My code works fine in other browsers, but in IE8 I get "error on page" - and when I click that it says:
"Exception thrown and not caught Line: 16 Char: 15120 Code: 0 
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"

I tried linking to jquery.js (rather than jquery.min.js) and to 1.5.1/jquery.min.js,
but problem still remains.

Can someone correct/improve my code for me, or guide me as to where to look.   Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbFetch() 
{
var token = "<<tag_removed>>&expires_in=0";

//Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/<<ID_REMOVED>>?&callback=?&access_token=" + token;

//Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
$.getJSON(url, function(json)
{
    json.data = json.data.reverse();  // need to reverse it as FB outputs it as earliest last!
    var html = "<div class='facebook'>";

    //loop through and within data array's retrieve the message variable.
    $.each(json.data, function(i, fb)
    {
        html += "<div class='n' >" + fb.name;           
        html += "<div class='t'>" + (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "ddd, mmm dS, yyyy")) + " at " + (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "h:MMtt")) + "</div >"; 
        html += "<div class='l'>" + fb.location + "</div >"; 
        html += '<div class="i"><a target="_blank" title="opens in NEW window" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/<<id_removed>>#!/event.php?eid=' + fb.id + '" >more info...</a></div>'; 
        html += "</div >";              
    }
    );
    html += "</div>";

    //A little animation once fetched
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function(){
        $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
    });
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

};

Comment: Your closing divs don't really have a space after div and before the >, correct? I don't see that being the issue, but ...

Comment: Thanks - corrected them, but as u suspected - problem remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the code do the job in IE8 or does it break? The reason I ask is because if it works as expected you could just wrap it in a `try{ } catch{ \\do nothing }` block and put it down to another thing IE is rubbish at.

You may be better off creating an object for the creation of the facebook div. Something like...

```
var html = $('<div />');
html.attr('class', 'facebook');
```

Then in your each loop you can do this...

```
$('<div />').attr('class', 'n').append(fb.name).appendTo(html);
$('<div />').attr('class', 't').append etc...
```

Then append `html` to the `facebookfeed` object

Doing this may remove the scope for error when using single quotes and double quotes when joining strings together, which in turn may solve your issue in IE8

```
$('.facebookfeed').fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).append(html).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

The append method is used to add *stuff* to a jquery object. For more info see [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

So to surround the div's as you mentioned in the comments you would do something like this...

```
var nDiv = $('<div />').attr('class', 'n').append(fb.name);
$('<div />').attr('class', 't').append(fb.somethingElse).appendTo(nDiv);
// etc
```

And then you would need to append that to the html div like so...

```
html.append(nDiv);
```

So that would give you

```
<div class="facebook">
     <div class="n">
         value of fb.name
         <div class="t">
              value of fb.somethingElse
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So what you have done is created a new jquery object and appended to that, then appended that to the html object which you have then appended to the facebookfeed div. Confusing huh?!

Comment: Thanks csharpsi - you have found the problem.

Comment: single & double quotes must have been the issue.

Comment: I'm still trying to get the new code right (I didn't even know DIVs could be self closing.  If I don't get it all right, may I come back to you to correct it for me?

Comment: Yes of course. Div's aren't self closing but JQuery performs some magic to create the DOM element as required. You could use $('<div></div') I think but the method I used earlier would provide the same result

Comment: Can you mark as answered if you feel it solved your issue please.

Comment: I have just noticed that you are not using the dom ready event. Make sure you wrap all your jquery inside $(function(){ //code goes here... }); otherwise it will not work.

Comment: It's all working (haven'ttested it yet on ALL browsers, but confident;-)

Comment: The only issue is the formatting ('cause I haven't yet understood your append lines of code.   I need the class 'n' div to enclose the class 'l','t, & 'i' divs.  I tried the following:

Comment: 'code'     $.each(json.data, function(i, fb)
     {
   $('<div >').attr('class', 'n').append(fb.name).appendTo(html); 
   $('<div />').attr('class', 't').append(fb.start_time).appendTo(html);      
   $('<div />').attr('class', 'l').append(fb.location).appendTo(html);
   tempTime = (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "ddd, mmm dS, yyyy")) + " at " + (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "h:MMtt")); 
   $('<div />').attr('class', 'i').append(tempTime).appendTo(html);
   $('</div>').appendTo(html); 
  );
'/code'

Comment: but it doesn't have the desired efect.
 (nb - I must stop pressing ENTER and inadvertantly adding a 1/2 finished comment!)

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your comments. I didn't notice you had wrapped the other divs in the `n` div sorry.

Comment: Your not going to believe this! ... but with the following code the same 'Exception' Error is back in IE8 (other browsers are OK)!
If I remove the 'tempTime' line and (in the .append) replace it by the original 'fb.start_time' it works fine.
Can you help once more please.

Comment: 'code'
     $.each(json.data, function(i, fb)
     {
   var nDiv = $('<div />').attr('class', 'n').append(fb.name);
    var tempTime = (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "ddd, mmm dS, yyyy")) + " at " + (dateFormat(fb.start_time, "h:MMtt"));
    $('<div />').attr('class', 'i').append(tempTime).appendTo(nDiv);
    $('<div />').attr('class', 't').append(fb.location).appendTo(nDiv);
    $('<div />').attr('class', 't').append(fb.id).appendTo(nDiv);
   html.append(nDiv); 
  }
  );
'/code'

Comment: Even if I just leave this line of code in:
'code'
    var tempTime = (dateFormat(fb.start_time, 'ddd, mmm dS, yyyy')) + ' at ' + (dateFormat(fb.start_time, 'h:MMtt'));
'/code'
and don't bother to append tempTime to the html,
It STILL fails with the same exception!!  So could it be an incompatibility between the dateFormat function Im using and jquery?

Comment: That does sound like that is what's happening. If you have the JQuery UI I would suggest trying to use the datepicker format function. I think the syntax is something like `$.datepicker.formatDate(format, date)` but make sure you have referenced the jquery UI library as well as jquery.

Comment: Thanks csharpsi, you lead me to the solution.  I found a date formater that doesn't conflict and its working now on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks VERY much 4 your excellent code and VERY quick response.